# Multiple Facebook app_id on same url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, app-id

Is it possible to have two Facebook App Ids on the same page? We wish to do this as we are adding a new Facebook app to a network of sites but want to avoid having to update each individual site's app. If we can have multiple apps we will be able to maintain a single app across all sites, while retaining the functionality of the legacy apps on the sites.

eg adding two open graph tags for app_id (Facebook linter seems to pick up both but I'm not sure if this will create other problems/complications):

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{APP ID 1}" /> 
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{APP ID 2}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no. We only allow a single app per page. I think the first one wins in our system. You can query it easily by visiting the graph API for that URL (the link is in the linter).