# How can add multiple og:site_name Facebook tags in the same domain website?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, liferay

I have multiple sites in Liferay and integrated Facebook meta tags to share, like on my website.
But I have problem with og:site_name for each site. All sites are the same domain.
Ex:

1. Site1:

   - Domain: https://XXXXX.org
   - og:site_name: XXXXX.org
   - FB Apps: XXXXXXXX123
2. Site2:

   - Domain: https://XXXXX.org/clothes
   - og:site_name: XXXXX.org/clothes
   - FB Apps: XXXXXXXX456

Two sites are using different apps and has the same domain.
My problem is that when I sharing anythings from site2 to Facebook, site name is displayed incorrectly although meta tags is correcly at all. It always show site name as site 1.

One more thing, I have used "Facebook Debugger", but this is the same.

Does anyone see this problem? please help me how to overcome this also.

Comment: You say that the site name is the same (and only mention XXXXX.org), then state that "the other" site name is used. Is it the same, or is it different? How do you differentiate between XXXXX.org (site 1) and XXXXX.org (site 2)?

Comment: Hi Olaf Kock, Liferay have multiple sites. The site 1 is always main domain (eg: XXXXX.org) and site 2 is same domain but more slash (XXXXX.org/web/<site_name_2>/home). This is feature of liferay when we want to have multiple sites of Liferay.

Comment: Are you running into this situation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262354/multiple-facebook-app-id-on-same-url

Comment: No Olaf Kock. For each page of each site, it just contains one FB app id and og:site_name. That means I don't generate the same FB meta tags in the same page.